# c# Reversing words in a string using single loop without using reverse function and stack

Tags: c#, string, text, reverse

I have tried writing the logic for reversing each word in a string with **single loop** but I didn't get it to work.  Can you please provide the logic to reverse every word in a string using single loop and without using reverse function.

Input:

> Welcome to the world

Output:

> emocleW ot eht dlrow

My Logic with two loops:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = string.Empty;
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] strarr=input.Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string str in strarr)
            {
                sb.Append(fnReverse(str));
                sb.Append(' ');
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static string fnReverse(string str)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            for (int i = str.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                result += str[i];
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply pass input string to your function fnReverse it should work

Answer (score 2):

```
    string strIn = "Welcome to the world";
    string strTmp = "";
    string strOut = "";

    for (int i=strIn.Length-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
        if (strIn[i] == ' ')
        {
            strOut = strTmp + " " + strOut;
            strTmp = "";
        }
        else
        {
            strTmp += strIn[i];
        }   
    }
    strOut = strTmp + " " + strOut;
```

Gives the result "emocleW ot eht dlrow"

Comment: this is just same as my answer

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani It does appear to be the same as yours, although this appears to have been posted before yours was edited to use this method.  I would suggest that you both arrived at the same answer independently.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Yes sorry, it was the last thing I posted before I logged off and then saw that you had edited yours to be the same. Great minds think alike and all that..

Answer (score 1):

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string result = "";
            string tmp = "";
            for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (input[i] == ' ')
                {
                    result =  tmp + " " + result;
                    tmp = "";
                }
                else
                    tmp += input[i];
            }
            result = tmp + " " + result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2kUCyo)**

Comment: Thanks for your response but if i consider over all program i should be using only one loop but in my code i have used 2 loops.

Comment: can you tell me what are these two loops? I don't get it. there is only one loop for reversing the string

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I think he is talking about the `foreach` that loops each word.

Comment: you can not have it with single loop. you may hide the loop for example using linq query but still it will be there

Comment: @Anandkumar now I get what you mean. please have a look at my edited answer